# A non well formed numeric value encountered in (PHP 7.4.30)

Tags: php, php7, numberformat

Me sale ese error **"A non well formed numeric value encountered in"** en PHP Version 7.4.30. El error sólo pasa cuando entra al else y específicamente en la línea que dice `return chr('0x'.$m[1]);`. El código de esa parte es el siguiente:

```
$Nombre=trim(isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : "");

function utf8Urldecode($Nombre)
{if (is_array($Nombre)){
        foreach ($Nombre as $key => $val) {
            $Nombre[$key] = utf8Urldecode($val);
        }
}
else{
  $Nombre=preg_replace_callback('/%([0-9a-f]{2})/mi', function($m)
  {
    //var_dump(chr('0x'.$m[1]));
    return chr('0x'.$m[1]);
  }, $Nombre);
}
    return $Nombre;}

$Nombre=utf8Urldecode($Nombre);
...
...
```

Como ven, antes había puesto la línea de `var_dump(chr('0x'.$m[1]));` y el cual me tira lo siguiente cuando lo corro:
**string(1) "" string(1) ""**

Acá [hay un ejemplo corriendo](https://onlinegdb.com/D0q4bbY8L) par que vean el error. Ahi he cargado una valor en la varibale *$Nombre* que contiene *Espectro_de_difracci%C3%B3n* (así viene la URL) y que luego de pasar esa lína con error debería quedar como *"Espectro_de_difracción"*.

La varibale *$Nombre* puede quedar cargada con palabras y tener caracteres raros (que reemplazan al acento) al ser URLs. Pero, como dije, después del proceso para que quede con acento, falla en la línea comentada.

Quizás existe otra forma mejor para que la palabra quede al final con el acento. Porque sino lo que hace al final es imprimirla de la forma *Espectro_de_difraccin* (como puden ver en el enlace que adjunto). Me suprime la vocal que tiene acento.

Estaba viendo que en JavaScript se usa para esto el método *decodeURIComponent()*.
Entonces algo como `decodeURIComponent(Espectro_de_absorci%C3%B3n)`
me quedaría luego de usar el método como *'Espectro_de_absorción'*.

¿Hay una función similar en PHP para lograr los mismo que en JavaScript?

Comment: ¿Y qué se supone que debe hacer esa línea que da error? Si lees el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.chr.php), verás que `chr()` admite como parámetro un entero, pero tú le estarías pasando una cadena, lo cual no es correcto. Pulsa en [edit] y clarifica tu problema.

Comment: Es que una cosa es el HTMLencode y otra, bieeen diferente, es que algo esté o no en UTF8...

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo he solucionado. He sacado todo ese else:

```
 else{
  $Nombre=preg_replace_callback('/%([0-9a-f]{2})/mi', function($m)
  {
    //var_dump(chr('0x'.$m[1]));
    return chr('0x'.$m[1]);
  }, $Nombre);
}
```

y lo he reemplazado con este:

```
else {$Nombre=rawurldecode($Nombre);}
```

*rawurldecode()* era el método que buscaba. Que como dice en su [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.rawurldecode.php) se encarga de decodificar cadenas codificadas estilo URL.

Comment: tu respuesta no tiene nada que ver con el error que presentaste en tu pregunta tampoco resuelve el error, lo que hiciste fue modificar la estructura del codigo y eliminar el codigo que daba error... pero eso no es una solucion.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 si que tiene que ver. Es una solución (alternativa) que me ha servido. Si te fijas, al final pregunto si hay alguna alternativa y buscando en la documentación de PHP encontre dicho método.

Comment: como se supone que debiamos llegar a esa respuesta alternativa ... nosotros no damos respuestas alternativas a menos que sean obvia o simples; tu has cambiado todo el contexto...